# Consulta com count

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, select, count

Tenho a seguinte tabela :

Status produto

```sql
SELECT id_produto_status_history, status, description, create_date, id_produto
FROM produto_status_history;
```

onde eu guardo o status do histórico do produto
Há um processamento que altera esse status e insere sempre uma linha nessa tabela com status diferente, POREM OS ITENS QUE não foram processados estão apenas com uma linha nessa tabela com status de CARRINHO.
Eu queria fazer uma select justamente para pegar esses caras. Pegar todos os produtos que tenham apenas a linha de status como CARRINHO, se tiver outra linha não tem que  vir no select. OU seja de acordo com a tabela abaixo o select deve retornar so o ID 58 E 59

então a tabela fica assim :

```
id_produto_status_history,     status,       create_date,         id_produto
      162                      CARRINHO     2021-08-06 18:27:24       56
      164                      PAGO         2021-08-06 18:39:43       56
      166                     ESTOQUE       2021-08-06 18:39:44       56
      168                     ENVIADO       2021-08-06 18:39:54       56
      162                     CARRINHO      2021-08-06 18:27:24       57
      164                      PAGO         2021-08-06 18:39:43       57
      166                     ESTOQUE       2021-08-06 18:39:44       57
      168                     ENVIADO       2021-08-06 18:39:54       57
      162                     CARRINHO      2021-08-06 18:27:24       58
      162                     CARRINHO      2021-08-06 18:27:24       59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer dessa forma:

- Agrupe por id_produto (`GROUP BY ID_PRODUTO`), isso vai permitir verificar cada produto.
- Pegue apenas os registros que a contagem for igual a 1, que ter apenas 1 status (`HAVING COUNT(ID_PRODUTO) = 1`).

O SELECT para retornar os produtos nessas condições fica assim:

```
select id_produto
  from historico
 group by id_produto
 having count(id_produto) = 1
```

Aqui usei o nome da table "historico", use o nome da sua propria tabela. Com os dados da sua pergunta, vai retornar os produtos 58 e 59.

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd54c/3)

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que entendi um select com where resolveria.

Select * from produto_status_history Where Status = "CARRINHO"

Comment: este comando sql compila?